# windows 11 wsl not opening gui in my ubuntu shell

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

I am running windows 11 and have updated my ubuntu instalation to wsl2. whenever I try to run something like xclock the it looks like it is running in the command line but no gui opens up. I've tried this with a number of applications and none seem to work.

I've used everything in these guides: https://github.com/microsoft/wslg https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe just remake the Ubuntu WSL machine. WSL on my Windows 11 machine is different than earlier versions.

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  When I saw your question on Stack Overflow, I knew we'd need some more information in order to answer it, but I quite sure to know what to ask since WSLg is pretty new (at least in released form).  I guess I was hoping that folks over here could come up with some good questions for you to help troubleshoot, but instead we seem to be getting "Close Votes".  Let me start with -- Is this a new/fresh Windows 11 installation, or was it an upgrade from a preview Windows 10 (or Windows 11 beta)?  Please edit the question and include that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue upgrading the WSL using the command line:

```
wsl --update
```

To restart it

```
wsl --shutdown
```

Then I used wslg to open the apps that doesn't register automatically into start menu using this command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wslg.exe ~ -d wsl-distro-name /linux/path/to/app/executable
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a hunch on *why* it's not working, but we'll need some additional troubleshooting to see for sure.

I don't normally recommend "reinstall", but I'm going to offer a slight variation on that here to see if it helps.

Try the following:

- Exit WSL/Ubuntu
- From PowerShell or CMD, issue `wsl --shutdown`
- From the Microsoft Store, install "Ubuntu 20.04".  This will install a *second* WSL instance (named "Ubuntu20.04") without modifying your existing installation. instance.
- Start Ubuntu 20.04
- `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- *Just* install a simple app like `xterm` and see if it launches

If it does, we can try to figure out why your default Ubuntu installation isn't worked and how to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Works on the Ubuntu 20.04 version. Guess i need to uninstall and reinstall it don't I?

Comment: @MyNameIsMyNameYourName If that's convenient for you, it may be the fastest path.  We may be able to find the problem, though.  I'm guessing it's something in the `~/.bashrc` or other startup config.  Just wondering, did you ever try to run any X apps before upgrading to Windows 11, using a Windows X server?

Comment: I reinstalled it. I backed up everything so it was an easy reinstall. Thanks though